# Have TeamCity pull a specific ChangeSet from TFS?

Tags: tfs, teamcity

I have a CI build in TeamCity that runs on check-in. I have a QA build that is run manually. I would like to specify which ChangeSet the QA build should use so it doesn't inadvertantly push changes that are not ready. Is there a way to tell TeamCity to tell TFS that we want to pull xyz changeset?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, use the "Run ..." button to the right of the build configuration you want to run (ie. click on the ... part).

[image: run custom build]

In that dialog you should be able to pick exactly which changeset TeamCity should use. Note that it seems TeamCity only sees changesets which have occured in TFS after TeamCity started monitoring the repository, so if you want to build against an old changeset you might still be out of luck.

[image: custom build dialog]